# form data is not getting posted to spring controller

Tags: spring, web-services, extjs

Form data:

```
form dat from UI developer tools
user.username:SS
user.email:SGFG@GMAIL.COM
user.firstName:WWW
user.lastName:FF
ext-gen1170:ENV_DEV
ext-gen1171:false
ext-gen1172:false
user.password:
userGroupPermissions:[{"userName":"SS","groupName":"ENV_DEV","permission":"*"}]
```

Web.xml for the dispatcher servlet:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>user</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/spring/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/createUser/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public String createUser(@RequestParam(value = "user.username", required = true) String username,
            @RequestParam(value = "user.email", required = true) String email,
            @RequestParam(value = "user.firstName", required = true) String firstName,
            @RequestParam(value = "user.lastName", required = true) String lastName,
            @RequestParam(value = "userGroupPermissions", required = true) UserGroupPermission userGroupPermissions,
            @RequestParam(value = "password", required = false) String password) throws IOException {
```

Above details will be added to handle the request

There are no errors in console but the breakpoint is not hit when I keep the break point in controller.

I am getting 404 for this code.

Extjs:
var url = '/spring/createUser';

Comment: Where is you're ExtJs code ?

Comment: Could you please add the rest of the controller?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to resolve this -- change the way you are sending parameters to Java or change the way you are receiving parameters.

### Just change Java

To keep things simple you should change Java.

1. GET requests should use `@RequestParam` arguments in Spring controllers in a way you specified.
2. POST/PUT requests should use `@RequestBody` argument in Spring controllers.

So the Spring controller should look like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value ="/createUser/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String createUser(@RequestBody UserParams params)
```

Obviously if you need the `@Transactional` part you should also leave it.

### Sending various requests with ExtJS

Here are some examples on how to use `Ext.Ajax.request` to send various types of requests.

I've used Polish in values so you can also see how encoding of UTF-8 text works.

#### Query string

Sending in query string means things get encoded directly in URL after `?`. E.g. `/test?firstName=Imi%C4%99&lastName=Nazwisko`.

```
// (Java/Spring can get this with `@RequestParam`)
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/test',
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
        firstName: 'Imię',
        lastName: 'Nazwisko'
    }
});
```

#### Form data

This is used when sending forms in a standard way. Things get encoded in the body of the request, but the format is actually the same as for the query string (e.g. `firstName=Imi%C4%99&lastName=Nazwisko`).

```
// (Java/Spring can get this with `@RequestBody`)
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/test',
    method: 'PUT',
    params: {
        firstName: 'Imię',
        lastName: 'Nazwisko'
    }
});
```

#### Request payload

This is a JSON communication. Things get encoded in the body of the request, but in a JSON format (e.g. `{"firstName":"Imi\u0119","lastName":"Nazwisko"}`).

```
// (Java/Spring can get this with `@RequestBody`)
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/test',
    method: 'PUT',
    jsonData: {
        firstName: 'Imię',
        lastName: 'Nazwisko'
    }
});
```

#### *Query string* in PUT/POST request

You can trick ExtJS to pass parameters in the URL rather then request body. When both `params` and `jsonData` are present in the `Ext.Ajax.request` one of them has to be put in the URL.

So to pass params in the query string use this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/test',
    method: 'PUT',
    params: {
        firstName: 'Imię',
        lastName: 'Nazwisko'
    },
    jsonData: {}
});
```

Note the empty `jsonData`. This will be encoded in request body as `{}` and can simply be omitted on the receiving end. In this case Java/Spring.

So this way you would receive all params as `@RequestParam` arguments in your Spring controller.